# Exception thread Error

Tags: java, macos, terminal

Well,when in run a Run `mac.command` program,it opens up terminal and makes an error,here it is.

```
Last login: Tue Dec 24 11:39:04 on ttys000
/Users/hisdadmin/Downloads/Destortion\ client\ v1.0/Run\ \(MAC\).command ; exit;
shaher-alneaswans-imac:~ hisdadmin$ /Users/hisdadmin/Downloads/Destortion\ client\ v1.0/Run\ \(MAC\).command ; exit;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
logout

[Process completed]
```

Would be great if i can get a fix asap

Answer (score 1):

The .class files were compiled for Java7 and you are probably running them with Java 6 or 5.

Comment: Yes,i'm using java SE 6...64-bit..... Version 1.6.0_26-b03-384 how can i change the .class into that?

Answer (score 0):

You might have more than one JDK installed..

You compiled your classes under a specific JDK, but trying to run them under older version of JDK. So, you can't run classes compiled with JDK 6 under JDK 5. The same with classes compiled under JDK 7 and running using JDK 6.

Uninstall all JDKs and install one.

Comment: [IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/ig97k2.png[/IMG] so uncheck it all and keep java 6 checked?

Comment: [IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/29zpvv6.png[/IMG] Didn't work.

Comment: Try with other versions once..